# Jenkins pipeline usage without chaining the jobs

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I want to get a chained job from start to the end. But these jobs are also needed for separate execution.

I want a scheduled build and need those jobs chained.

When running manually,  not running the Jobs in cascaded mode.

I don't want to click configure, remove downstream run and re-add the downstream in case of manual execution.

What is the best solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Jenkins pipeline as code? Jenkinsfile? This can be done, I know how with 'as code' but it sounds like you might be gui based, which I don't have an answer for.

Comment: I added my answer below regardless

Comment: Actually what I am thinking about currently after going through multiple blog post and websites is can I just introduce a string parameter for this job which indicates that I want the post build action to trigger the downstream job else I'll not trigger the post build action maybe I can dynamically influence the individual build as unstable or failed or something so the post build isn't executed. And for chained this parameter will be set and thus post build will get a stable status to trigger downstream.

Answer (score 1):

So this can be done, however I do recommend putting the functions I have outlined below in a Jenkins Shared Library. Doing it this way will cause at least 4 sandbox security approvals, which will require your jenkins administrator to approve. 1 of which warns it is a security vulnerability.... so assess the impact for your environment and your risk profile.

```
#!groovy

List jobparameters = [
        booleanParam(name: 'CHECKBOX', defaultValue: true, description: 'Tick a checkbox'),
        string(name: 'STRING', defaultValue: 'stringhere', description: 'Enter a string')
    ]

properties([
    pipelineTriggers([cron('''TZ=Australia/Victoria
            H 1 * * *''')]),
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '20')),
    parameters(jobparameters),
])


stage('Stage') {
    node {
        // do something always
        echo(params.STRING)
    }
}
if ( hasAutomatedCauses() ) {
    stage('folder1/reponame/branch') {
        //do something conditionally
        build(job: "folder1/reponame/branch", parameters: jobparameters, propagate: true)
    }
} else {
    stage('folder1/reponame/branch') {
        node {
            echo("Not running downstream job")
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Checks if job causes contain automated causes
 * Return true if automated cause found
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
boolean hasAutomatedCauses() {

    List automatedCauses = ['UpstreamCause', 'TimerTriggerCause']

    List intersection = []
    intersection = automatedCauses.intersect(getCauses())

    // if no automated causes are found means intersection is empty and then return false
    return !intersection.isEmpty()
}

/**
 * Retrieves list of causes that generated job execution
 *
 * @return list
 */
List getCauses() {

    return currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().collect { it.getClass().getCanonicalName().tokenize('.').last() }

}
```